# How to remove some files from index and push rest of them to remote repository?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I want to remove some heavy files from index and push rest of the files from my local repository to remote repository but even after removing it from index all files are being getting pushed.

I have tried using `git rm -r --cached` command to delete files from a directory and then `git commit` and finally `git push` to push rest of files in the index but the deleted files also get pushed again. I tried it twice but no luck.

```
Akshat@LAPTOP-8O95UD76 MINGW64 ~/ImgAug (ImgAugmentation)
$  git rm --cached -r labelled_dataset
rm 'labelled_dataset/test1_sec0.jpg.csv'
rm 'labelled_dataset/test1_sec10.jpg.csv'
rm 'labelled_dataset/test1_sec100.jpg.csv'

Akshat@LAPTOP-8O95UD76 MINGW64 ~/ImgAug (ImgAugmentation)
$ git status
On branch ImgAugmentation
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
deleted:    labelled_dataset/test1_sec0.jpg.csv
        deleted:    labelled_dataset/test1_sec10.jpg.csv
        deleted:    labelled_dataset/test1_sec100.jpg.csv

Akshat@LAPTOP-8O95UD76 MINGW64 ~/ImgAug (ImgAugmentation)
$ git add ImgAug.py

$ git commit -m "bbox & image display"
[ImgAugmentation 030492f] bbox & image display
 1556 files changed, 7349 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 labelled_dataset/test1_sec0.jpg.csv
 delete mode 100644 labelled_dataset/test1_sec10.jpg.csv


Akshat@LAPTOP-8O95UD76 MINGW64 ~/ImgAug (ImgAugmentation)
$ git push origin ImgAugmentation
Enumerating objects: 1558, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1558/1558), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1555/1555), done.
Writing objects:   1% (20/1557), 12.63 MiB | 194.00 KiB/s

Writing objects:   3% (49/1557), 39.67 MiB | 222.00 KiB/s
Akshat@LAPTOP-8O95UD76 MINGW64 ~/ImgAug (ImgAugmentation)
$
```

Comment: You cannot push files: you can only push whole commits (which, admittedly, *contain* files). It's up to the other Git to decide what to do with those whole commits once you send them. Note that if you push some commit `H` whose parent is `G`, with `G`'s parent being `F`, and so on, and if the other Git has only commit `F`, your attempt to send `H` sends *both* `G` *and* `H`. So if existing commit `G` has some huge files, and you try to make a slimmed-down `H` that has fewer files and then send `H`, you're still sending the huge files by sending `G`.

Comment: How should I send `H` instead of `G`. Can you pls tell it using code?

Comment: The point is that you *can't*. You need to make some commit(s) that connect to a chain that they have—that are in their Git—that add on to those commits, that do not have the large files. In general this means creating a new branch in your own repository, starting from the tip commit of one of their branches, and adding new commits that are improved versions of your original commits, with the improvement being that you leave some files out.

Comment: oh man. Thanks by the way.